# Trying to build something like in video

Tags: java, android, animation

I'm new at programming in Android studio and am trying to do something like this video down below. I don't know what should I use and how even to start, is this something like a collapse toolbar or something else? Thanks for the help :)

[Video click here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kiHJowm-Tj4HEx_asAvVny2VIuKwUkl_)

Thanks all,
Peace :)

Comment: The link you provided is not working for me. Can you post any other?

Comment: Ok, I did it, you can try again now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use:

- CoordinatorLayout
- AppBarLayout
- CollapsingToolbarLayout

Here I found "similar" issue.
[Issue with CoordinatorLayout and ImageView that adjusts width while scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41458682/issue-with-coordinatorlayout-and-imageview-that-adjusts-width-while-scrolling)

If you don't want your immage to fade completely, you can always set:
app:layout_collapseMode="pin"